# Timestamps in Laravel 5 got 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, timestamp

I have just started using Laravel 5 and I have problem with timestamps. When I seed a table, everything going good and I get e.g.

```
created_at
"2015-04-04 20:02:21"

updated_at
"2015-04-04 20:02:21"
```

But when i use `Order::insert(array())`
i get:

```
created_at
"0000-00-00 00:00:00"

updated_at
"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
```

In laravel 4 I need not set timestamps manually, so I believe, I need not do it there too.

Comment: You should check the database for a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you're using Eloquent. Instead of using `insert()` method you should create new record in DB like this:

```php
$order = new Order;
$order->save();
```

In this case Eloquent will maintain the created_at and updated_at columns on your database table automatically

Comment: Thatks. I solved problem using  "$order = new Order; $order->user_name = $request->input('username'); $order->save();" But create([]) doesn't work, so i need rewrite my array